# Notation in the book Symmetry by Hermann Weyl

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, notation

I'm having troubles understanding a notation of the symmetry groups in a book "Symmetry" by Hermann Weyl. On the page 80 of the 1952 Princeton University Press edition of the book, Weyl lists the three-dimensional point groups. Can somebody, who has read this book and has knowledge of these groups (I am at the very beginning of studying group theory), translate his notation to [Schönflies notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_notation) which I am more familiar with?

Comment: Could you make the question self-contained by adding the relevant portion of Weyl's text?

Answer (score 1):

$T, W, P$ $\to$ $T, O, I$

$C_n \to C_n$

$D'_n \to D_n$